# Selenium Test Case writing practice

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am new to automation testing and selenium and have been watching alot of selenium tutorials. I realized that selenium test cases are written in 2 formats and im not sure which one to go with.
1)

```
namespace SeleniumTests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Login
    {
        private IWebDriver driver;
        private StringBuilder verificationErrors;
        private string baseURL;
        private bool acceptNextAlert = true;

        [SetUp]


    public void SetupTest()
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            baseURL = "http://chapters.com";
            verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void TeardownTest()
        {
            try
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
            }
            Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
        }

        [Test]
        public void TheLoginTest()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginCtrl_UserName")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginCtrl_UserName")).SendKeys("operations");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginCtrl_Password")).Clear();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginCtrl_Password")).SendKeys("welcome");
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginCtrl_LoginButton")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnInitialLoad")).Click();
            Assert.AreEqual("Chapters", driver.Title);
        }
    }
}
```

2)

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;

namespace TestProject1
{

    public class UnitTest1
    {

        public void main()
        {
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            string baseURL = "http://seleniumhq.org/";
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseURL);
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Projects")).Click();
            driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Selenium IDE")).Click();
            Assert.AreEqual(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='mainContent']/table/tbody/tr/td/p/b")).Text, "Selenium IDE");
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Which one do I go with? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second scenario is simple sequential flow of statements without added advantage of any frameworks like Junit,TestNG,Nunit. It is good for people who have just started with Selenium 2.0 and want to practice with different methods provided by webdriver.

The first scenario is logical division of the code into different annotations provided by Nunit, with these annotations one can get tremendous power of the underlining framework being used, in your case Nunit, these annotation are automatically called by the Nunit framework in a defined order. Apart from this there are multliple other functionalities provided by these frameworks like Reporting,Assertions,Support for Mock Objects,etc

Always use the first scenario for writing Selenium code because along with understanding of the webdriver code, one also gets hang of the underlining framework.

Comment: When there is only 1 testMethod, the annotations are called by the Nunit framework in the [setUp][test][tearDown] order. But what is the sequence when there are multiple testMethods/[test] in that class? Are each testMethod an individual Nunit test?

Comment: yes this should ideally be the case, each method annotated with [Test] should be a different test case

Comment: If I needed to test features of a web app where the features are A,B,C,D,E,F,G and I had to features of the app go in the order of A->B->C->D->E->F->G. To test each feature, do I create 7 testMethods where Method1{A}, Method2{A->B}, Method3{A->B->C}, Method4{A->B->C->D}, Method5{A->B->C->D->E}, Method6{A->B->C->D->E->F} and Method7{A->B->C->D->E->F->G}? I was thinking that A test script would just test the app in the order A->B->C->D->E->F->G and if there is an error it just breaks and report the error.